# How to run a DAX Query from java program?

Tags: java, ssas, dax, analysisservices

DAX Query :

```
evaluate
(
   summarize
   (
     'Internet Sales',
     'Internet Sales'[Sales Order Number],
     'Internet Sales'[Sales Order Line Number]
   )
)
order by
  'Internet Sales'[Sales Order Number],
  'Internet Sales'[Sales Order Line Number]
```

How can I execute above query from a java program?